# Struggling With Conditional Validation MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

been trying to fix this for a few days now and just cant get it to work!

i have a radio button list which determines the output of a form - one of the radio buttons is to download X amount of files. this radio button has a text box for the user to enter the amount (X) they wish to download.

i only need this textbox to validate if the radio button that corresponds to it is selected - this is what i have so far but cannot get it to work. any help would be appriciated.

MODEL

```
public class myClass

{
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the type of output you wish to generate")]
       public int providerType { set; get; }


       public int? numOutput { set; get; }


       public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
       {
           if (providerType == 2 && numOutput == null)
               yield return new ValidationResult("Description must be supplied.");
       }

}
```

CONTROLLER

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Spin(myClass theData)

    {

        int? ProviderType = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["providerType"]);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //other random processing

        }

    }
```

VIEW

```
   <ul>
<li>
  <%=Html.RadioButton("ProviderType","1")%><label>Output A Single Article (With Visible HTML Tags)</label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <%=Html.RadioButton("ProviderType","4")%><label>Output A Single Article (With HTML Pre Rendered - Not Recommended For Articles With Videos)</label>
 </li>
  <li>
  <%=Html.RadioButton("ProviderType", "3")%><label>Output For Mass Submission</label> 
  </li>

 <li>
  <%=Html.RadioButton("ProviderType", "2")%><label>Download Several Copies Of Article (With Visible HTML Tags)</label>
 How Many Artilces (Max 20) 

            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.numOutput)%>
             <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.numOutput)%>
```

im still new to MVC so im probably doing something stupid here - any help is much appriciated. The error im getting is that when i select the radio button and dont enter anything in the textbox "Input string was not in a correct format." so obviously the validation is not firing - cant quite figure out why.

Comment: How are you trying to validate it?  with model.validations or with js?  if it is in the model then you have validate input turned off so it won't ever catch it.

Comment: Thats probably why - i disabled it because there are textboxes on the page that im allowing html tags to be input in. Although there is other [required] validation in the model that is being executed correctly

Comment: Ok i removed validate input = off to test it and still had no luck.

Comment: @Brian - ValidateInput does not control model validation, it controls input validation, which ensures that the input does not contain dangerous code.  It has nothing to do with model validation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why its not hitting Validation is because your model is not implementing IValidatable Object.

```
  e.g. public class MyClass:IValidatableObject
```

Let me know if that works for you. I was able to get the above code working locally and can send you the code if it still doesnt work for you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx